# Microstrategy multiple filtered metrics based on same attribute

Tags: report, reporting, microstrategy, metric

I have an attribute called vehicle type and I want to create two filtered metrics based on this attribute. so I created two metric that gets count of vehicle and applied filter vehicle type = bus and vehicle type = car on the other one. on my report I want to show a line charts with these two metric against day, also user should be able to filter by vehicle type using selector. The problem is when I create a dataset containing vehicle type, day and those two metrics, microstrategy returns empty dataset.

Answer (score 2):

By default MicroStrategy uses inner join for your metrics.

Of course in your case no vehicle is a car and a bus too, so you need to tell MicroStrategy to do an outer joins for the two conditional metrics that you created.

To do so just go to `Menu Data -> Report Data Options` and change the Metric Join type for the report where you have these metrics.

You can also decide to change the default Join Type at database instance level, but I don't think this is really necessary if you have this problem only for these two metrics.

For more details you can also check [TN11721: What are the settings to consider when performing an Outer Join between metrics in MicroStrategy Engine 9.x?](http://community.microstrategy.com/t5/Architect/TN11721-What-are-the-settings-to-consider-when-performing-an/ta-p/172386)

[image]